# How do you deal with two vertical scrolls on a webpage using selenium c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Has anyone dealt with two vertical scrolls on a webpage.  Inner vertical scroll for the iframe that is on the page the outer scroll on the very main webpage.  There are times where i need to handle the outher scroll and i'm not able to interact with it.  I've tried a more then a few different codes like

```
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

or finding an element down the page to scroll to like

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: \"auto\", block: \"center\", inline: \"nearest\"});", selctentity);
```

nothing i've done worked like i want it to work.

Like i stated i want to scroll the outer scroll vertical bar.

Comment: To work in iframe you have switched webdriver windowHendler, right? To work with main page, did you switched back to default context?

Comment: Did you try scrolling with Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();  Also did you tried switching driver to frame as well as mentioned by @GennadyZyablitsev

Comment: @GennadyZyablitsev I've tried that.  that didn't work. I switched out of iframe and picked an element that was below the page. It found the element but the scrolling didn't work

Comment: @PankajDevrani are you saying that actions will perform the scroll.  The issue is currently the element is not visible on the page even though the the inner scroll screen have scroll to the very end and just need the outer scroll to scroll down a bit to launch it.

Comment: @skinnyWill I didn't come across such situation, which you have mentioned in the question but it does scroll automatically to the element and brings it to the front. You can try and find out if it works for you.

Comment: @PankajDevrani I've tried your suggestion and I get an error of  Here is the exception System.InvalidOperationException: move target out of bounds\n  error.  since the element isn't visible on the page.

Comment: Is it possible to share url?

Comment: @KunduK its not possible i can include an image it that will make it easier

Comment: @skinnyWill In such scenarios my strategy would be to execute the tests using a headless browser with a super large width+height so that the scrollbars are effectively gone. In that way you don't have to worry about handling scrolling, and also the chance of introducing flakiness to the tests. Will that work for your case?

Comment: Can you post HTML and Images?

Answer (score 0):

As far as scrolling is concerned, if you are using IWebElement you can use `element.ScrollTo()` method to scroll to any element. However you have an iframe in the inner scroll and your issue is with outer scroll. If your outer scroll is not in any iframe then switch to default content to do anything. If your outer scroll is also inside another iframe then you will have to switch to that one.